# How to deal with separator format in Swift 3

Tags: string, swift3, double, nsformatter

Having a great deal of trouble finding a way to (Formating) remove comma and if no comma found then leave as it is.

What I am hoping to achieve is taking the result of a distance and displaying it in a Label so that the format is:

### 4589.163

instead of

### 4,589.163

If no comma separator found then leave it as it is

### 479.996

My code:

```
if tempDistanceString.contains(",") {
       let newString = tempDistanceString.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: "")
}
```

I'm looking for Formatter if supportable to my requirement.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Formatters are expensive to create and configure. I think using "replacingOccurrences(of:with:)" is probably your best option here.
Is this something you'll be calling often? If so, you could probably use a NumberFormatter to convert your string to a number, and a second formatter to convert back to your desired format string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use numberFormatter with property `usesGroupingSeparator` set to false

For example:

```
let formatter = LengthFormatter()
formatter.numberFormatter.usesGroupingSeparator = false
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3.1**

Just replace occurrences of comma with blank string.

```
let aString = "4,589.163"
let newString = aString.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: "")
```